# Scale and fade upon page opening

Tags: html, css, jquery-animate, scale, transition

First issue:
I have been trying to get this right but nothing is working. Just as the page is loaded, i want an image to scale and fade down and sit there. The image is also a link.

The code I have so far that works without any animations is

html---

```
<a href="index.html"> 
    <img src="images/insandoutslogo.jpg" alt="" class="insandoutslogoimg" /> 
    <p1> Ins and Outs </p1>
</a>
```

css---

```
.insandoutslogoimg
{
    width: 210px;
    height: 210px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -112.5px;
    margin-left: -112.5px;
}
```

THanks heaps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's  hard to understand the question. But maybe you are looking something like this:

```
.insandoutslogoimg {
  width: 210px;
  height: 210px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -112.5px;
  margin-left: -112.5px;

  animation: fadeInDown 2s ease;
}

@keyframes fadeInDown {

  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

[CodePen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/reimd)

You also need [browser prefixes](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-deal-with-vendor-prefixes/) (CodePen uses Lea Verou [-prefix-free](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/))

Comment: thats exactly what im looking for but it doesn't work when i add the code to my code...? i even specified -webkit-animation: fadeInDown 2s ease; and it did nothing.. any ideas?